# Why does paper-input need a double click in IE in Polymer

Tags: polymer

When I do this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'></script>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html'>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html'>
</head>
<body unresolved>
    <paper-input></paper-input>
    <paper-dialog style='width:100px;height:100px' opened>
    </paper-dialog>
</body>
```

Then the paper-input does not get focus immediately when clicked in IE 11. I need to click it some times before the cursor appears.

If I remove the

```
<paper-dialog style='width:100px;height:100px' opened>
</paper-dialog>
```

From the page, then the paper-input recieves focus immediately.

I have tried jsbinning it, but it does not seem to work at all in IE http://jsbin.com/cuhubazuwi/1/edit?html,output

Any hints appreciated :-)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with webcomponents-lite so I have moved to that